# Would StackExchange please turn on community-ads for us?

Tags: support, status-declined

I believe we need to put in a request to have community ad functionality turned on for our CiviCRM community site, so here's my request on our behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time. Community ads are one of those features that are enabled when the site graduates.

[**Community Promotion Ads**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/)

Comment: Oh well. Something to look forward to.

Comment: I've been trying to unbundle these features from "graduation" forever. I've been making some headway in dribs and drabs, but I cannot promise anything.

Comment: Thanks for advocating this!